Printing specific pages of an epub with Calibre
Apparently there is no plugin for Calibre to convert the epub3 into images which would keep the flow of text seen in the reader.
Therefore, I've tried to print the epub, but it does not work either.
Can't Calibre alternatively convert to images?

@beaker Print option is literally available natively in the Caliber viewer, so what are talking about?

Given that the Calibre viewer - and most other epub viewers - reflow text based on window size and text size, is it even meaningful to speak of 'pages' in an epub document?

@JeffZeitlin The epub that concerns us shows the exact same pages in Caliber as the physical version; changing width or height does not work in the viewer.

Which in turn prompts the question of whether it's text at all, rather than an image of the page. I don't generally see ePubs that behave that way unless they're pure images; that sort of behavior with actual text is more expectable for PDFs or similar formats that are intended to replicate the printed page (such as Microsoft's XPS).

if that ebook shows the exact same pages in Calibre as the physical version it could be that the "sections" of the ebook are the single pages. If this were the case, probably the best option is to use an epub editor like Sigil and export the relevant sections.

Care to elaborate a bit further?
